# Prove or disprove that $\lim_{n→∞}\sup_{x∈R}⁡f_n (x) =\sup_{x∈R}⁡f(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of function defined and bounded on $\mathbb R$, and suppose that $\{f_n\} $converges uniformly to $f$ on every finite interval $[a,b]$. Prove or disprove that 
>   $$\lim_{n→∞}\sup_{x∈R}⁡f_n (x) =\sup_{x∈R}⁡f(x).$$

I know that $\{f_n\} $converges uniformly to $f$ that mean $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup |f_n -f| \to0$. But it's not necessary that $\lim_{n→∞}⁡\sup_{x∈R}⁡f_n (x) =\sup_{x∈R}⁡f(x)$.

I don't think this is true, But I can't find counter example either.

Comment: Isn't $f_{n}(x) = I(x=n)$ a counter-example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
f_n = \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \text{ if } x \ge n \\
0 & \text{ if } x < n \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Given any finite interval $[a,b]$ and any $\epsilon > 0$, just pick $N > b$ and we have that $f_n = 0$ on $[a,b]$ for $n > N$.  Thus $f_n \to {\textbf{0}}$ uniformly on $[a,b]$.

Comment: I cannot understand why it is downvoted.

Comment: @sos440 I've receieved 4 or 5 downvotes in the past half hour on some of my recent answers.  They are probably hate-downvotes from the same user.

Comment: I cancelled out that suspiciously malicious voting. Hope this will make you feel better.

Comment: @sos440 thanks `:D`